# can't find mod_wsgi.so after yum installation

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to move an old client to a new server and get WSGI working for his django backend. I installed wsgi using yum; the httpd -M command shows that it is installed. However, the file mod_wsgi.so appears to be nowhere on the server. Earlier I had tried to include a WSGIScriptAlias command in the httpd.conf file, and received this error:

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_main_global.conf.tmp: Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration --- /etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_main_global.conf.tmp --- 1 ===> WSGIScriptAlias /spdre /home/pdr887629/django/sullivan/wsgi.py <=== --- /etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_main_global.conf.tmp ---
```

Another Stack Overflow solution on that error message said I should include this first:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

But the mod_wsgi.so file does not actually exist in that directory, or anywhere else on the server. How can I get mod_wsgi working? Do I need to reinstall via another method, or is there somewhere I can go from here (with the current install)?

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it under /etc/apache2/modules/. Not sure why the find command did not locate it.